# Copy files from Solaris to redhat via SCP command run on RedHat console

Tags: scp, redhat-enterprise-linux, solaris

I have to copy several GB of little files (from few bytes to < 1MB).

These files resides on a file system of a Solaris system.

No `rsync` and `rdiff` software is available on Solaris and cannot be installed.

The question is which command can be used to do it and how?

I need to issue the command several times, avoiding to copy already existing files on destination (RedHat) and possibly remove files/directories not existing anymore on the source since last execution (differential copy).

Answer (score 0):

If SSH is installed on Solaris and you can access the system via SSH then you could `scp like this from the RedHat destination:

```
scp -rp solaris_user@solaris_host:/path/to/files/* /redhat/destination/path/
```

Answer (score 0):

> No `rsync` and `rdiff` software is available on Solaris and cannot be installed.

Arhh. C'mon. It ain't that difficult:

`pkg install network/rsync`

But then again, afaik, `rsync` is part of the default install of Solaris since 2005 (Solaris 10) so you shouldn't need to install it.

But maybe you are on a system that hasn't been touched in the last 10-15 years?  (which sometimes, in Solaris world, isn't unusual)